# Google App Engine, Datastore validation for login

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm working on some code where if the user enters a username and password equal to what is stored in datastore they are granted access.

Problem 1:
currently i want the program to display the username and password if they are found in the datastore, However, whatever i enter is displayed back.

Problem 2:
While checking datastore i want it to only look at the password for the user that is logging in, not all the passwords.

code:

- all php files are correctly connected to datastore.

login.php:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="validate" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="username" required><br>
Password: <input type="text" name="password" required><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

validate.php:

```
 $currentUser = $_POST["username"];
 $currentPass = $_POST["password"];

 $keyU = $datastore->key('User', $currentUser);
 $taskU = $datastore->lookup($keyU);
 echo $keyU;

 $keyP = $datastore->key('User', $currentPass);
 $taskP = $datastore->lookup($keyP);
 echo $keyP;
```

I was wondering how i should approach this, any helpful guidance would be very help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can do query the datastore with the following GQL query

```
SELECT * FROM Companies WHERE username = @username && password = @password
```

so that you won't be fetching the whole set of data instead you will fetch only the particular entity if the given username and password matches